# Sapper - protected routes (route guard)

Tags: routes, svelte, sapper

My question is very simple. How do you prevent, e.g. non authorized user, to enter specific routes in sapper?

user.svelte

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    onMount(() => {
      if(!authenticated)
        window.history.back()
      });
</script>
```

Is there any option to run some code before mounting to the DOM?

How do you solve this kind of problem?

Thank you.

Comment: it is best to do it in the server.js file,

Answer (score 8):

I can't say it's the right thing. It's what I do in my SPAs. If I want to protect all routes of my app. I create following in `_layout.svelte` top file.

```html
<script context="module">

    import {ax} from './_parts/Helper.svelte'
    import {admin, adminName} from './store'
    import {goto} from '@sapper/app'

    export async function preload(page) {
        try {
            const {data} = await ax.get('/admin/is-logged-in')
            adminName.set(data)
            admin.set(true)
        } catch (e) {
            admin.set(false)
        }
    }
</script>

<script>
    import Login from './admin/login.svelte'
    import {loading} from './store.js'
</script>

<main>
{#if $admin}
     <slot></slot>
{:else}
     <Login />
{/if}
</main>
```

`ax` is nothing magic. It's just configured axios.
`'/admin/is-logged-in'` is where you check session at backend.

Comment: This works good, but imagine e.g. some user roles, admin, editor, writer,... how to protect different routes based on your role?

Comment: Well, at abstraction level. After login you can fetch the user role from db and save that role inside ``store.js``. After that you can protect component using if-else condition blocks.

Comment: The way I've implemented this feels wrong to me myself. The proper approach should be using the session argument passed to ``preload``. See this https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Argument

Comment: @YousufIqbalHashim how do you access the store in `preload()` if it executes on the server?

Comment: Good Idea!
I did the same with flutter where I created a widget that checks if the user is logged in. If so it returns its child. Otherwise it returns a loging widget.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I had basically the same problem. I posted [question (with solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58691278/sapper-event-for-route-change) here on SO and solved it the same day with help from [this issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/30#issuecomment-514393015) from Sapper GitHub with my own "*auth redirecting middleware*".

Answer (score 1):

Let me generalize that problem.
We should implement session state synchronization between client and backend.
What the best way to do that? It's a difficult question. It depends.

For example, if you try to protect something valuable when the remote users just try to access restricted areas it's pretty simple. Just redirect to sign in/signup page. But what if the one remote user logout and the second user try to log in at the same application at the same browser before reloading from backend? We quickly jump to the logic trap. So how to correctly manipulate with DOM tree accordingly to the remote session state?

[image: Transition between routes]

Probably the best way to do that, just control transitions between routes.
In sapper, you should do that by exporting the [preload](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Preloading) function for every module.

So instead place logic into _layout.svelte (so easy but not sapper way in my opinion). We should create a general module `route-guards.js` as an example.
Then we should import it into every module.

The rest of an answer:

```js
    // route-guards.js
    export async function transitionControl(self, page, session) {
        const result = await self.fetch('/is-logged-in');  // self for support server side rendering
        const response = await result.json();
    
        if (!response && page.path !== '/login') {
            return self.redirect(302, '/login');
        }
    }
```

```svelte
    <!-- any module.svelte -->
    <script context="module">
        import { transitionControl } from "./route-guards";
    
        export async function preload(page, session) {
            await transitionControl(this, page, session);
            // Do another what you want before page load
        }
    </script>
```

Please keep in mind that the sync states between two things never be easy as you want. OMG web development so difficult. Thanks, everyone for pay attention.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Yousuf for your answer. I tinkered around with it and came up with an alternative solution that redirects to a login page if the user is not logged in.

I also did not want all routes to be protected, since the user must be able to login and register. Therefore I use the page object to determine the route the user wants to navigate to and I also check the session object if a login token is present (e.g. a JWT). This check could be modified to suit your needs.

**_layout.svelte**

```
<script context="module">
  const publicRoutes = ['/login', '/register'];

  export async function preload(page, session) {
    if (publicRoutes.indexOf(page.path) === -1 && !session.token) {
      this.redirect('302', 'login');
    }
  }
</script>

... The rest of your component here ...
```