# Sapper event for route change

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

I need to redirect users to login page if they are not authenticated. I need something like `route.beforeEach` in Vue.js, ideally:

```js
sapper.beforeRouteChange((to, from, next) => {

  const isAuth = "[some session or token check]";

  if (!isAuth) {
    next('/login')
  }

  next()
})
```

I found [Sapper - protected routes (route guard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58153372/sapper-protected-routes-route-guard) this question but I think it's not enough for my needs. What if token or auth changes in runtime? OR is it covered by reactivity?

**Edit 1:** I think that [this](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/30#issuecomment-514393015) issue on Sapper GitHub solves my problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I placed this code to `/src/routes/_layout.svelte`:

```js
  import AuthMiddleware from "../methods/authMiddleware.js";
  import { goto, stores } from '@sapper/app';
  const { page } = stores();

  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && typeof document !== "undefined") {
    page.subscribe(({ path, params, query }) => {
      const from = window.location.pathname;
      const redirect = (href) => { goto(href); }

      AuthMiddleware.beforeChange(from, path, redirect, params, query);
    })
  }
```

And this is `authMiddleware.js` file:

```js
export default class AuthMiddleware {

  static beforeChange(from, to, redirect, params, query) {

    if (!AuthMiddleware._isUserAuthenticated()) {
      redirect("/login");
    }
  }

  // ~

  static _isUserAuthenticated() {
    return true; // TODO: Implement
  }
}
```

more information on route hooks can be found here

- https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/30
- https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs/#Stores

Comment: How I can redirect specific pages here? like profile page if lot login redirect to login page.

Comment: I like this solution but how is `AuthMiddleware.beforeChange()` executed before the route change? In my experimentation any callback passed into subscribe is called after the store changes. Further, I've found `from` and `to` are equal because the route change has already happened by the time the function is executed. I'm only asking because I'm curious what you did beyond whats included in the answer.

Comment: Yeah sorry. It is possible that `beforeChange` is not really called *before* the route change (It was just some good sounding name that I liked). I just needed SOME solution for my problem and at that time this was enough for my needs. If you find something better, feel free to edit my answer (or send me an DM and I will edit it myself).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `authenticationMiddleware.js` inside `server.js` file

Here is `authenticationMiddleware.js` file

```
import { get, post } from "./../lib/api";
async function authenticationMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    let user = null
    const cookies = require('cookie-universal')(req, res);
    if (cookies.get('token')) {
        try {
            user = await get("users/me", null, cookies.get('token'));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('err at users', e.toString());
        }
        req.user = user
        req.token = cookies.get('token')
    } else {
        req.user = {}
        req.token = null
        cookies.set('token', null)
    }
    next();
}
export { authenticationMiddleware }
```

e.g. https://github.com/itswadesh/sapper-ecommerce/blob/master/src/server.js

Comment: Would this work on exported static version ot the app?

Comment: I think the issue you're going to run into here is that sapper is a little bit _too_ efficient. Once you get the main chunks over to the client calls for rendered components happen infrequently. From what I can tell, [`beyonk-adventures/sapper-rbac`](https://github.com/beyonk-adventures/sapper-rbac) has the most complete solution to date but they still need that client-side part.